# return value from Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, button, return, textfield

I've got this function, I want to return a value when I click on the button. I know it doesn't work, but how do I fix this? I already googled about it, but couldn't find something relevant.

My code:

```
public String OutputText()
{
    layout.show(mainpanel, "PANEL");
    testbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            return textfield.getText();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why you want the function to return value?

Comment: what do you want to with the 'returned' value?

Comment: So this wil work: 'system.out.println(OutputText()); for example :)

Comment: Why dont you just do that inside the listener?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value from `actionPerformed()` and even if you could, it wouldn't affect what's returned by your `OutputText()` method. When you run your `OutputText()`, it adds an `ActionListener` to the button, but the method will be called asynchronously only when the button is pushed. That's why there can be a long time between calling `OutputText()` and when `actionPerformed()` is called.

If you want to display what's written in the textfield, you can put `System.out.println(textfield.getText())` inside the `actionPerformed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CallBack approach and pass the return value to the Call back interface:

```
public class TestCallBack {
    JButton testbutton;

String value;

public interface Callback {
    void setResult(String result);

}

public class MyCallBack implements Callback {
    @Override
    public void setResult(String result) {
        value = result;
    }
}

public static abstract class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private Callback callback;

    public MyActionListener(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

}

public String OutputText() {
    layout.show(mainpanel, "PANEL");

    testbutton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(new MyCallBack()

    ) {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            this.callback.setResult(textfield.getText());


        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a value from a void method. You can however print it out. Alternativey, you can call a Method that returns a value for example:

```
public String returnStringValue(){
return textfield.getText();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

lblAnotherlabel.setText(returnStringValue);
   }
```

But Why do all that if you can achieve this directly?